# jBPM Business Application: not able to get REST server (error 500)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jbpm, kie

I managed to get the jBPM Business Application from https://start.jbpm.org/ and followed step by step guide https://docs.jbpm.org/7.58.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_launch_application
I successfully launch the business application with "business-service/launch.bat clean install". I managed to get to the main page "http://localhost:8090/"

However, when I tried to access "http://localhost:8090/rest/server" with the default "user" credentials, I have the following error from my web browser:
[Error500][1]
Whitelabel Error Page

***This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.***

````
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

From the server logs, I can see this:
2021-08-14 09:53:01.428  INFO 19584 --- [           main] o.k.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl   : Container business-chopper-kjar-1_0-SNAPSHOT (for release id com.bikerzon:business-chopper-kjar:1.0-SNAPSHOT) successfully started
2021-08-14 09:53:01.444  INFO 19584 --- [           main] o.k.server.services.impl.KieServerImpl   : KieServer business-chopper-service is ready to receive requests
2021-08-14 09:53:01.580  INFO 19584 --- [           main] o.k.s.s.a.KieServerAutoConfiguration     : KieServer (id business-chopper-service) started successfully
2021-08-14 09:53:01.900  INFO 19584 --- [           main] org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl       : Setting the server's publish address to be /
2021-08-14 09:53:02.200  INFO 19584 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
2021-08-14 09:53:02.224  INFO 19584 --- [           main] com.bikerzon.service.Application         : Started Application in 26.283 seconds (JVM running for 28.248)
2021-08-14 09:58:53.330  INFO 19584 --- [0.0-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-08-14 09:58:53.330  INFO 19584 --- [0.0-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-08-14 09:58:53.340  INFO 19584 --- [0.0-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2021-08-14 10:00:33.203 ERROR 19584 --- [0.0-8090-exec-4] c.s.x.b.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector  : null

java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:558) ~[na:na]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:197) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:81) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:125) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:402) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayProperty.<init>(ArrayProperty.java:68) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.<init>(ArrayERProperty.java:88) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:100) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementLeafProperty.<init>(ArrayElementLeafProperty.java:70) ~[jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]```

Please help


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNPIy.png
````

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using java 16 (please confirm) and there is a new feature (https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/396) that sets the default value of the launcher option --illegal-access to "deny" instead of "permit".

You could either use explicitly "--illegal-access=permit" in the launcher or downgrade java version.